# Updating an OpenStruct field with strong parameters and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Attempting to add :preferences to devise's strong parameters as

```
preferences: [:gender, :location, :website, :aim, :interests])
```

generates the error

```
Attribute was supposed to be a OpenStruct, but was a ActionController::Parameters. -- {"gender"=>"No", "location"=>"", "website"=>"", "aim"=>"", "interests"=>""}
```

Adding :preferences as just

```
:preferences
```

throws no errors but none of the key-value pairs are updated when the form is submitted. Fields other than :preferences, such as :email and :password, are updated correctly.

I've done my googling but can't figure out the format to indicate a nested OpenStruct in the strong parameters sanitizer.

The logger output confirms that :preferences is unpermitted.

controllers/application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  [snip]

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { 
        [snip]
    }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { 
        |u| u.permit(:name, :email,
                     :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password,
                     preferences: [:gender, :location, :website, :aim, :interests]) 
    }
  end
```

models/user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, OpenStruct
  after_create :default_preferences

  def default_preferences
    self.preferences.gender = ''
    self.preferences.location = ''
    self.preferences.website = ''
    [snip etc.]
  end
```

views/devise/registrations/_form

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <!-- Control panel -->
  <% unless params[:page] %>

    [snip default control panel page]

  <% end %>

  <% case params[:page] %>
  <% when "password" %>

    [snip fields for password change]

  <% when "email" %>
    [snip fields for email change]

  <% when "profile" %>
    <%= f.fields_for :preferences, OpenStruct.new(f.object.preferences) do |p| %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= p.label :gender %>
        <div class="input">
          <%= p.text_field :gender %>
        </div>
      </div>

      [snip etc. preferences fields, e.g. :location, :website, :aim]
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <!-- Submit -->
  <div class="field">
    <div class="input">
      <%= f.submit "Update profile", class: "update-button" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to override the assignment of preferences to cast as the type expected:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  …
  def preferences=(val)
    return super if val.is_a? OpenStruct
    super OpenStruct.new val.to_h if val
  end
end
```

This code will call the original settor method if the value is already an `OpenStruct`, and otherwise will try to convert the value to a hash before converting that hash to an `OpenStruct`. Note that this will raise an error if the value can't be converted to a hash.

I think this is the best solution because specifying the `serialize` type as `OpenStruct` means that the value assigned should *always* be an instance of `OpenStruct`, and this code will ensure that.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! Very succinct solution.